# How to make multiple quires in firebase database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase in my Android app. I need to check the value of two attributes in my query but when I use OrderByChild method more than one time I got an error how can I solve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using OrderByChild more than once isn't allowed in firebase , However you can make a third child that contains the two attributes you want to check their value.For example if your two childs contains the two values username,userEmail you can create a third child and concatenate the user name and email in it so you can use this third child to do your query on.